# all key-values did not match for jsonschema

Tags: karate

I have jsonschema like this below :

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "rc": "51",
    "product": {
        "code": "28",
        "label": "PLN",
        "type": "electricity",
        "ops": "PLN",
        "nominal": 50000
    },
    "cust_id": "01428800200",
    "order_id": "",
    "ref_no": "2033930693200733",
    "amount": 50000,
    "price": 50000,
    "created": -62135596800
}
```

and this is my schema validation

```
{
  "id": "#number",
  "rc": "#string",
  "product": {
    "code": "#string",
    "label": "#string",
    "type": "#string",
    "ops": "#string",
    "nominal": "#number"
  },
  "cust_id": "#string",
  "order_id": "#string",
  "ref_no": "#string",
  "amount": "#number",
  "price": "#number",
  "created": "#number? _ < 0"
}
```

but I get message `reason: all key-values did not match` , but I think that my schema is correct, so does anyone can help me with this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, you must have some mistake in your script. Paste the below into a fresh feature file and see it working for yourself:

```
* def response = 
"""
{
    "id": 0,
    "rc": "51",
    "product": {
        "code": "28",
        "label": "PLN",
        "type": "electricity",
        "ops": "PLN",
        "nominal": 50000
    },
    "cust_id": "01428800200",
    "order_id": "",
    "ref_no": "2033930693200733",
    "amount": 50000,
    "price": 50000,
    "created": -62135596800
}
"""
* def schema =
"""
{
  "id": "#number",
  "rc": "#string",
  "product": {
    "code": "#string",
    "label": "#string",
    "type": "#string",
    "ops": "#string",
    "nominal": "#number"
  },
  "cust_id": "#string",
  "order_id": "#string",
  "ref_no": "#string",
  "amount": "#number",
  "price": "#number",
  "created": "#number? _ < 0"
}
"""
* match response == schema
```